# Vue.js, vuetify.js Accordion do not open

Tags: vue.js, accordion, vue-component, vuejs2

I have a custom component `blog` and with an accordion (from vuetify.js) I show the posts in the blog (at the end ul>li) using a second custom component blog-post. I tried it without nesting and it worked fine. With the nesting of custom component I can expand and close only the first post.

Here the code. The template of `blog.vue`:

```
<template>
  <v-content class="blog">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row>
        <v-col xs3="xs3"></v-col>
        <v-col xs6="xs6">
          <h5>Blog</h5>

          <div class="loading" v-if="loading">
            Loading...
          </div>

          <div v-if="error" class="error">
            {{ error }}
          </div>

          <div v-if="posts" class="content">
            <v-collapsible>
              <template v-for="post in posts" >
                <blog-post :post="post"></blog-post>
              </template>
            </v-collapsible>
          </div>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-content>
</template>
```

And the template of `blog-post.vue`:

```
<template>
  <li class="blog-post">
    <v-collapsible-header>{{ post.title }}</v-collapsible-header>
    <v-collapsible-body>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text class="grey lighten-3">{{ post.body }}</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-collapsible-body>
  </li>
</template>
```

Heders and bodies of the accordeon are filled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `<template v-for` try `<li v-for`, like following inside  **blog.vue**:

```
      <div v-if="posts" class="content">
        <v-collapsible>
          <li v-for="post in posts" >
            <blog-post :post="post"></blog-post>
          </li>
        </v-collapsible>
      </div>
```

and in  template of **blog-post.vue**:

```
<template class="blog-post">
    <v-collapsible-header>{{ post.title }}</v-collapsible-header>
    <v-collapsible-body>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text class="grey lighten-3">{{ post.body }}</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-collapsible-body>
</template>
```

Comment: I tried this variant, and I get the error: `template syntax error Component template should contain exactly one root element:`

Comment: @LiPo Does putting everything in a div in `blog-post.vue` helps, possible to create a fiddle of it?

Comment: it doesn't work either. I think I will keep a single component with all posts